# Simplify multiple summations involving Kronecker deltas

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find a specific answer to it.

These work, i.e. they simplify:

`Sum[KroneckerDelta[a, 5] f[a], {a, Infinity}]
f[5]`

`Sum[DiscreteDelta[a - 5] f[a], {a, Infinity}]
f[5]`

And:

`Sum[KroneckerDelta[a, n] f[a], {a, Infinity}]`

`Sum[DiscreteDelta[a - n] f[a], {a, Infinity}]`

also simplify when explicitly indicated, i.e. when invoking `Simplify` / `FullSimplify`.

But simplifications over multiple summations don't work, even for the simplest of cases:
`Sum[KroneckerDelta[a, 5] f[a], {a, Infinity}, {b, Infinity}]`

`Sum[DiscreteDelta[a - 5] f[a], {a, Infinity}, {b, Infinity}]`

**Edit**: As mentioned, this specific example is not good. Here is the original case that motivates my question:

$\sum_{a=0}^\infty \sum_{b=0}^\infty  f(a) f(b)\ \delta_{a, b}$

that is,

`Sum[f[a] f[b] KroneckerDelta[a, b], {a, 0, Infinity}, {b, 
  0, Infinity}]`

which can be simplified to a single sum:

$\sum_{a=0}^\infty f(a)^2$

Can *Mathematica* be instructed to simplify expressions like these?

Thanks.

Comment: Your double sums are infinite, there's no way *Mathematica* can give you a result for them.

Comment: You can sometimes simplify multiple infinite sums involving Kronecker deltas into a single infinite sum. I hope it's clearer now with the new example.

Answer (score 3):

use [assumptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) with [`PositiveIntegers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositiveIntegers.html) instead of [`NonNegativeIntegers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonNegativeIntegers.html):

```
Assuming[Element[n, PositiveIntegers], 
  Sum[KroneckerDelta[a, n] f[a], {a, Infinity}]]
(*    f[n]    *)

Assuming[Element[n, PositiveIntegers], 
  Sum[DiscreteDelta[a - n] f[a], {a, Infinity}]]
(*    f[n]    *)
```

Comment: Thanks, those work, yes. It seems I had some already defined values that were messing with the simplification rules. I'll edit the question.

Comment: In fact these work without assumptions, that is, just by invoking `Simplify` on them.

Comment: On my system, without assumptions the command `Sum[KroneckerDelta[a, n] f[a], {a, Infinity}] // Simplify` returns `f[n] UnitStep[-1 + n]`, as it should. Please always try your code in a fresh kernel.

Comment: My result matches yours... it's already a simplification, so, that's OK. Please take a look at the multiple sum at the end of my (edited) question. I'm in fact asking about that case.